# Erro sdk ao fazer build de aplicativo android abaixo de api nivel 24

Tags: android, ionic, apache-cordova, build, android-sdk

Construí um aplicativo simples para teste. Quando faço build para versões de android sdk igual ou superior a 24 ele reconhece o SDK e faz o procedimento correto, mas se tentar fazer build de outras versões como a 22 e 23 (Android 5.1 e 6.0) aparece erro e o procedimento não é concluído. Se for  o SDK 23 a situação é ainda pior pois não consegue nem mesmo adicionar a plataforma Android ao projeto do ionic, diferentemente da API nível 23, que por sua vez adiciona a plataforma mas não consegue fazer o build.

**O que ja tentei:**
Adicionei o caminho do sdk e do gradle como variável de sistema pelo gerenciador do windows, troquei varias vezes as versões de SDK para teste, chegando a conclusão que o SDK só não funciona quando inferior a 24, atualizei o gradle e já adicionei os comandos :

```
set ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Herick Pereira\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
```

**Erro que aparece:**

```
Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
```

**Configuração usada:**

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.12.3 (C:\Users\Herick Pereira\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@ionic\cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.5.2
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.1000.8
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 10.0.8
   @angular/cli                  : 10.0.8
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 2.3.3

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 10.0.0
   Cordova Platforms : android 7.0.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.2.0, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.2.1, (and 4 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : 1.3.0

System:

   NodeJS : v14.15.4 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.14.10
   OS     : Windows 10
```

Comment: Amigo tentou remover e adicionar a plataforma?

Comment: Oi obrigado pelo comentário, reinstalei o jdk, setei novamente  o java_home e reiniciei o pc ai funcionou